# unable to setColorFilter for stickerview

Tags: android

am using sticker view in my project . it's a library that extend imageView and let you move and rotate image on the screen 
https://github.com/nimengbo/StickerView
my problem is that i can't set color filter for images , i have tested every thing 
such as

```
mCurrentView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_alpha_95), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        mCurrentView.getDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_alpha_95), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

or even making a new drawable from resource and add that drawable to image view ;

i will be greauful if you have any experience with setColorFilter issue or know another lib or approach to move image view on the  screen and share it with me

Comment: why MULTIPLY? what effect do you want to apply?

Comment: @pskink  the effect is not important . it is now working at all even if i do not add any effect . but totally i have some sofa . and i want to change their color based user chose . as i tested them all MULTIPLY is best of them

Comment: you cannot use color filter here - the guy who wrote it completely overrode `onDraw` method and no color filter is supported: see: `StickerView#onDraw`, the line `canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, matrix, null);`

Comment: @pskink thanks dear for cheking library .. so  there is no way to use filter color ? i shoud look for another approach ?

Comment: you have the sources, so change them - you have the line that draws the bitmap so it shouldn't be that hard

Comment: sry i read them a lot but i did'nt get them . actually i,am a litle noob at cooding . i will be really greatful  from you if you help me what change should i Apply .

Comment: you should use a `Paint` with your `ColorFilter` applied

Comment: @pshknik my you write an example pleaaaase .  and if write it in answer that i can acept your anser

Comment: i wrote what you should do - your job is to implement it in StickerView's code - just use right `Paint` whan calling `drawBitmap`

Answer (score 0):

I'm use tint using compat support lib.

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red_alpha_95);
Drawable drawable = mCurrentView.getDrawable();
Drawable wrap = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrap.mutate(), color);
```

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.mutate()' on a null object reference              ty @betorcs but i got it . it's now working :(